# change logger.exception to level=CRITICAL instead of ERROR?

Tags: python

I need to change the logger.exception default behavior to write to my logger with level=CRITICAL. It seems like something I can change but I haven't figured out how. My last resort is sys.excepthook but I don't want to use it because I do formatting in there.

thanks!

Comment: If you want to use a warning level that doesn't have a shortcut for it just use `logging.log(logging.CRITICAL, msg)`.  Though apparently there is a `logging.critical()`.  This is how you can use custom levels as well.  I'm not entire sure that's what you're asking though.

Comment: In response to your comment: `logger.exception(...)` is equivalent to `logger.error(exc_info=True)`, so what I said should work. Did you actually try it? And just to clarify, `logger.exception()` does *not* cause a raising of the exception by itself, you would need to explicitly add a `raise`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can log exceptions using `CRITICAL` like this:

```
logger.critical('Message with %s', 'arguments', exc_info=True)
```

which will behave just like `logger.exception`, only with a level of `CRITICAL` rather than `ERROR`.

Comment: The problem is that logger.exception is not a logging level, it's a special function that is meant to be placed in a catch to log the exception and traceback to a file. typically after logger.exception is called, the exception is raised.

Comment: @mna Good point about `logger.exception` being different, but you shouldn't log *and* raise an exception - do one or the other, otherwise you can end up with the same exception being logged multiple times.